# Show for $f(-x) = -f(x)$ that $F(-x) = F(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given a continuous real function $f$ with  $f(-x) = -f(x)\, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, show that the antiderivative $F$ satisfies $F(-x) = F(x)\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

What I did was to take the definition of the derivative to obtain

\begin{align*}
f(-x) = \lim_{h\to -x} \frac{F(h)-F(-x)}{h+x} = -f(x) = -\lim_{h\to x}\frac{F(h) - F(x)}{h-x}
\end{align*}

From this I got to

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{h\to -x} \frac{F(h)-F(-x)}{h+x} = \lim_{h\to -x} \frac{F(-h)-F(x)}{h+x}
\end{equation*}

Now I am not completely sure how to proceed, since I haven't done any rigorous math in a while.
Since from above follows

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{h\to -x} \frac{F(h)-F(-h)}{h+x} = \lim_{h\to -x} \frac{F(x)-F(-x)}{h+x}
\end{equation*}

my idea was to argue that since it has to be valid $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, the only way to satisfy this is if $F(x) = -F(x)$.
Not sure if I'm correct in that regard though or if it is even rigorous enough, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It can't be true in such a general way, because an antiderivative is not unique: it is defined up to an additive constant.

Comment: In other words, you want to show that the antiderivative of an odd function is even.

Comment: @Bernard You have for any antiderivative $F$ that $F(x) =F(-x) $ though you don't have $F_1(x)=F_2(-x)$ where $F_1,F_2$ are two different antiderivatives.

Comment: @kingW3: I meant that speaking of **the** antiderivative  is meaningless.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed, I misunderstood you.

Comment: I probably also didn't formulate it unambiguously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, you can write

$F(x) = F(0) + \int_0^x f(t)dt$.

From the fact that $f(-t)=-f(t)$, it's simple to show that $F(-x)=F(x)$.

Comment: Note that this works in this case because $f$ was given to be continuous. In general, it not true that if $f$ has an anti-derivative, then $f$ is integrable. Indeed, it may be that $f$ is not even bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Consider the function which is $x^2sin(1/x^2)$ for non-zero $x$ and is $0$ at zero. This is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ but its derivative $f$ is not integrable since it's not bounded near $0$. A bounded example can also be obtained, you may look up the Volterra function.

Answer (score 4):

You have $(F(x) - F(-x)) '=f(x) +f(-x) =0$ so $F(x) - F(-x) $ is constant   and we have $F(0)-F(-0)=0$ so $F(x) - F(-x) \equiv 0$

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, talking about *the* anti-derivative is not correct.

Here's a better version of the question:

> Let $F : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable with derivative $f := F'$. Suppose that $f(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
> Show that $F(x) = F(-x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Note that this is also a tougher question since $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. In this case, the other answer using $F(x) = F(0) + \int_0^xf$ will not work since $f$ need not be integrable.

(It's possible for a derivative to not be integrable? Sadly, yes.)

The idea of the other answer now works. Consider the function $G : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as $G(x) = F(x) - F(-x)$.
Then, for an arbitrary $x \in \Bbb R$, elementary properties of the derivative tell us that $G'(x)$ exists and $$G'(x) = f(x) - -f(-x) = f(x) + f(-x) = 0.$$

Thus, $G'$ is identically zero. Now, since the domain is an *interval*, we may conclude that $G$ is constant. Evaluate $G$ at $0$ to see that this constant must be $0$.

(Was domain being an interval important? Yes. Consider $G : (-2, -1) \cup (1, 2) \to \Bbb R$ defined as $G(x) = x/|x|$. Then, $G$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain and the derivative is identically $0$. However, $G$ is not constant.)